# jQuery - Manage Data

Tags: jquery, graph

I need to easily manage data with jQuery
my page has a lot of Graphs, and this is how it works:

```
categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                    'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
series: [{
                name: 'Tokyo',
                data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
            }
```

I dont have access to SQL, so i have to manage my data with javascript...
Is there a easy way to manage my data to generate those graphs?

Answer (score 0):

Try this : http://d3js.org/

Very useful for generating graphs.